# Ошибка в SQL запросе для PostgreSQL для INSERT INTO ON CONFLICT

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет.

Есть у меня такие две таблицы в двух схемах в одной БД:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS target_redshift.dim_collect_projects (
            project_id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            project_number BIGINT,
            project_name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
            connect_project_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
            project_desc VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,
            project_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            project_status VARCHAR(100),
            project_path VARCHAR(32768),
            language_code VARCHAR(10),
            country_code VARCHAR(10),
            timezone VARCHAR(10),
            project_created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
            project_modified_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
            date_created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
            date_updated TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
        );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS source_redshift.dim_collect_projects (
            id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            number BIGINT,
            name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
            connect_project_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
            description VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,
            type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            status VARCHAR(100),
            path VARCHAR(32768),
            language VARCHAR(10),
            country VARCHAR(10),
            timezone VARCHAR(10),
            created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
            modified TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
```

Мне нужно скопировать данные из второй таблицы в первую таким образом, чтобы в случае, если id из второй есть в project_id в первой, то применялся ON CONFLICT DO...

Я сделал такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO target_redshift.dim_collect_projects
        SELECT s.id, s.number, s.name, s.connect_project_id, s.description,
        s.type, s.status, s.path, s.language, s.country, s.timezone, s.created,
        s.modified
        FROM source_redshift.dim_collect_projects AS s
        ON CONFLICT (s.id = project_id)
        DO UPDATE SET
        (project_number, project_name, connect_project_id, project_desc,
        project_type, project_status, project_path, language_code,
        country_code, timezone, project_created_at, project_modified_at) = (EXCLUDED.number, EXCLUDED.name, EXCLUDED.connect_project_id,
         EXCLUDED.description, EXCLUDED.type, EXCLUDED.status,
         EXCLUDED.path, EXCLUDED.language, EXCLUDED.country,
         EXCLUDED.timezone, EXCLUDED.created, EXCLUDED.modified)
```

Но я не уверен относительно того, правильно ли я делаю здесь ON CONFLICT (s.id = project_id).

И еще мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при копировании из второй в первую или обновлении при ON CONFLICT в колонках в первой таблице date_created и date_updated данные просто добавлялись для date_created из системного времени сервера когда данные были добавлены а для date_updated из системного времени когда данные были обновлены (в случае, если IN CONFLICT).

Вот тут у меня немного недопонимание как это сделать. Можете подсказать как поправить мой запрос, чтобы он выполнял условия?

Спасибо.

Comment: А [документацию](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) почитать и примеры в ней посмотреть не пробовал? а зря... ON CONFLICT в качестве параметра требует index_column_name или index_expression, а никак не выражение.

Comment: Ну почему же - читал. Только написано там довольно топорно и не понятно как по мне. Может из-за отсутствия опыта соответсвующего. И примеры там довольно урезанные.

Comment: Там написано - либо указывать индексированное поле, либо набор полей из индекса. Про выражение там нет ни полслова. В общем, должно быть `ON CONFLICT (project_id)`, а само поле должно быть первичным индексом либо уникальным полем.

Comment: А как оно понимает, что нужно сравнивать project_id именно с id из другой таблицы? Оно смотрит какие уникальные или первичные индексы есть в обеих таблицах? А если в одной из таблиц будет несколько уникальных?

Comment: Сервер просто вставляет записи (из источника, указанного во FROM) в таблицу. При этом проверяются всякоразные ограничения, в том числе первичного индекса и уникальных индексов. Если обнаруживается ошибка дублирования, сервер проверяет, что дублирование обнаружено именно в указанном поле или наборе полей. Если так - выполняется ON CONFLICT, если в ином индексе - генерируется ошибка исполнения. Проблемы, что с чем сравнивать - нет, сравнивается то, что вставляется, с тем, что уже имеется.

Comment: Ааа, ну да, теперь понимаю. Спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: См. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=999ff399069fee907d700da753fd54d7

Comment: Класс! Большое спасибо!